# How to create several lists with for loop in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I am having two text files as follows: animals.txt and birds.txt,

where the words inside those files are separated by a ';'

Now, I have to retrieve those files based on user input and store the content inside 2 separate lists.

The code which I tried in shown below:

```
import os

text = []

for a in list: # Here list consists of the names of files and user explicitly declares the names of those files!
    c = open(os.getcwd(),'r')
    for x in c:
            d = x.split(";")
            text[a] = d
```

The output which I am expecting is text[animals] = ['tiger', 'shark',...] and text[birds] = ['parrot', ...]

But I am getting a type error as follows: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Definitely `a` is str. Did you read: *"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"*? Do you know about dictionaries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211600/discussion-between-vivek-and-austin).

Comment: That is because you are trying to assign a key to a list text[a] = d you probably want to declare the text = {} that may help with the assigning of d list into a key value of a.